# Finding the null space of a peculiar differential operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need to find the null space of the differential operator subject to Neumann boundary conditions $K : C_N^2[0, \ell] \to C[0, \ell]$ defined by
$$
Ku = -\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \alpha u, \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
$$
in order to apply it to my PDE, however I'm not sure if my steps are correct. What I've tried so far is the standard procedure of solving the ODE
$$
-u''(x) + \alpha u(x) = 0
$$
which gives me the char. eqn.
\begin{align*}
-r^2 + \alpha &= 0 \\
r &= \pm \sqrt{\alpha} \\
\end{align*}
so then the general solution is
\begin{align*}
u(x) &= c_1e^{(\sqrt{a})t} + c_2e^{-(\sqrt{a})t} \\
u'(x) &= c_1(\sqrt{a})e^{(\sqrt{a})t} - c_2(\sqrt{a})e^{-(\sqrt{a})t}.
\end{align*}
Applying the Neumann B.C.s I get
\begin{align*}
u'(0) &= c_1(\sqrt{a}) - c_2(\sqrt{a}) = 0 \Rightarrow c_1 = c_2 \\
u'(\ell) &= c_1(\sqrt{a})e^{(\sqrt{a})\ell} - c_1(\sqrt{a})e^{-(\sqrt{a})\ell} = 0 \Rightarrow c_1 = 0 \ (\mathbf{?})
\end{align*}
and the null space is trivial ($\textbf{?}$).

My questions are: Was it correct to assume $r$ is not complex when looking for the null space? Should I have shown that the null space is also trivial if $r$ is a complex conjugate pair of roots?

EDIT:
Now checking the complex conjugate pair of roots case I have
\begin{align*}
u(x) &= c_1\cos((\sqrt{a})x) + c_2\sin((\sqrt{a})x) \\
u'(x) &= -c_1(\sqrt{a})\sin((\sqrt{a})x) + c_2(\sqrt{a})\cos((\sqrt{a})x).
\end{align*}
Applying the B.C.s I get
\begin{align*}
u'(0) &= c_2(\sqrt{a}) = 0 \Rightarrow c_2 = 0 \\
u'(\ell) &= -c_1(\sqrt{a})\sin((\sqrt{a})\ell) = 0 \Rightarrow c_1 = 0
\end{align*}
Therefore, the null space is trivial (since if $\sqrt{\alpha} = 0$ then we have $1$ real root of multiplicity $2$) $\textbf{?}$

Assuming the repeated root also yields a trivial solution, would this be a proper way to show that the null space of $K$ is trivial?

Comment: You should also consider the complex case. You will then find $\cos$ and $\sin$ which satisfies the boundary conditions.

Comment: @ArcticChar should I always consider both the real and complex roots when looking for the null space of these types of operators?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ArcticChar after what I've added to my post, is it correct to conclude that the null space of $K$ is trivial?

Comment: Note that at the end you do not have $c_1 = 0$ if $\sin (\sqrt a \ell) = 0$.

Comment: And you need also to deal with the remaining case: $a=0$

Comment: There are not complex roots (check $\sin(\sqrt{a}x)$, it is not a solution of the ODE). And, why are you surprised about the result you get?

Comment: @RafaBudría why wouldn't $\sin(\sqrt{\alpha} x)$ not be a solution? I just plugged it into the ODE and it works...

Comment: For the first derivative $u'=\sqrt{a}\cos(\sqrt{a}x)$. For the second one, $u''=-a\sin(\sqrt{a}x)$ or $-u''=a\sin(\sqrt{a}x)$. So, $-u''=au$ and $-u''+au=2au\neq0$